# Переделать Intent в Fragment

Tags: java, android, камера

При клике по кнопке срабатывает этот метод:

```
public void onRecordVideo(View v) {
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            File mediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myvideo.mp4");
            videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Нет камеры", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

И он переходит в камеру, и при нажатии на галочку переходит обратно. И видео играет в `VideoView`.

Вопрос: Можно ли сделать так чтобы при клике по кнопке, не открывалась новая страница а открывалась в `VideoView` или в каком нибудь другом блоке, но только в этом `Activity`? Если да, то как?

Comment: используйте preview камеры и записывайте видео своим способом, а не с помощью стандартной камеры.

Comment: вы хотите записывать видео в своем приложении, не используя приложение Камера?

Comment: Да, записывать видео в блоке LinearLayout или еще что, не открывая приложение Камера

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо добавить SurfaceView в разметку. И используя Camera, SurfaceView, SurfaceHolder записывать видео своим способом.
Вот детальный пример [http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/264-urok-132-kamera-vyvod-izobrazhenija-na-ekran-obrabotka-povorota.html ] [http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/266-urok-133-kamera-delaem-snimok-i-pishem-video.html ]

Comment: Camera же устарело??